# Python Regex: remove underscores and dashes except if they are in a dict of string substitutions

Tags: python, regex, string, dictionary

I'm pre-processing a string. I have a dictionary of 10k string substitutions (e. g. `"John Lennon": "john_lennon"`).  I want to replace all other punctuation with a space.

The problem is some of these string substitutions contain underscores or hyphens, so I want to replace punctuation (except full stops) with spaces unless the word is contained in the keys of this dict.  I also want to do it in *one* Regex expression since the text corpus is quite large and this could be a bottleneck.

So far, I have:

```
import re
input_str = "John Lennon: a musician, artist and activist."
multi_words = dict((re.escape(k), v) for k, v in multi_words.items())
pattern = re.compile("|".join(multi_words.keys()))
output_str = pattern.sub(lambda m: multi_words[re.escape(m.group(0))], input_str)
```

This replaces all strings using the keys in a dict. Now I just need to also remove punctuation in the same pass. This should return `"john_lennon a musician artist and activist."`

Comment: Leave the final full stop, really?

Comment: @tripleee PO said, "I want to replace punctuation (except full stops)".  I guess this also applies to the final full stop.

Comment: Yep, the full stops are needed for me to segment the sentences down the line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it by adding one more alternative to the constructed regex which matches a single punctuation character. When the match is processed, a match not in the dictionary can be replaced with a space, using dictionary's `get` method. Here, I use `[,:;_-]` but you probably want to replace other characters.

Note: I moved the call to `re.escape` into the construction of the regex to avoid having to call it on every match.

```
import re
input_str = "John Lennon: a musician, artist and activist."
pattern = re.compile(("|".join(map(re.escape, multi_words.keys())) + "|[,:;_-]+")
output_str = pattern.sub(lambda m: multi_words.get(m.group(0), ' '), input_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the punctuation you would like to remove like the entries in your dictionary:

```
pattern = re.compile("|".join(multi_words.keys()) + r'|_|-')
```

and

```
multiwords['_'] = ' '
multiwords['-'] = ' '
```

Then these occurrences are treated like your key words.

But let me remind you that your code only works for a certain set of regular expressions.  If you have the pattern `foo.*bar` in your keys and that matches a string like `foo123bar`, you will not find the corresponding value to the key by passing `foo123bar` through `re.escape()` and then searching in your `multiword` dictionary for it.

I think the whole escaping you do should be removed and the code should be commented to make clear that only fixed strings are allowed as keys, not complex regular expressions matching variable inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can add punctuations (excluding full stop) in a character set as part of the items to match, and then handle punctuations and dict keys separately in the substitution function:

```
import re
import string

punctuation = string.punctuation.replace('.', '')
pattern = re.compile("|".join(multi_words.keys())+
                     "|[{}]".format(re.escape(punctuation)))


def func(m):
   m = m.group(0)
   print(m, re.escape(m))
   if m in string.punctuation:
      return ''
   return multi_words[re.escape(m)]

output_str = pattern.sub(func , input_str)
print(output_str)
# john_lennon a musician artist and activist.
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a regex like `(?:alt1|alt2...|altN)|([^\w\s.]+)` and check  if Group 1 (that is, any punctuation other than `.`) was matched. If yes, replace with an empty string:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"(?:{})|([^\w\s.]+)".format("|".join(multi_words.keys())))
output_str = pattern.sub(lambda m: "" if m.group(1) else multi_words[re.escape(m.group(0))], input_str)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Q5M19l).

A note about `_`: if you need to remove it as well, use `r"(?:{})|([^\w\s.]+|_+)"` because `[^\w\s.]` (matching any char other than word, whitespace and `.` chars) does not match an underscore (a word char) and you need to add it as a separate alternative.

Note on Unicode: if you deal with Unicode strings, in Python 2.x, pass `re.U` or `re.UNICODE` modifier flag to the `re.compile()` method.